# How can I correct this : time data '9121991' does not match format '%d %m %Y' error?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, python-datetime

I am attempting to calculate the age of a person from their date of birth entered, using python.

I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862525/valueerror-time-data-does-not-match-format-y-m-d-hms-f) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662606/valueerror-time-data-140209-1729-does-not-match-format-ymd-hm) but have not found the answer.

I have done the following :

> Import datetime, date

```
from datetime import datetime, date
```

> Create the following notation:

```
print ('Enter your date of birth here (dd mm yyyy): ')
date_of_birth = datetime.strptime(str(input('----->')), '%d %m %Y')


def calculate_age(born):

    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - (( today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))

age = calculate_age(date_of_birth)

print (age)
```

However when I enter the date in this format `9121991` :

I get this value error.

[image]

Incidentally when I enter it in this `09121991` format, I recieved this error

[image]

How can I correct this?

Comment: `09121991` is interpreted as octal by `input` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your format has spaces in it, it is unable to recognize your string.

That works:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

date_of_birth = datetime.strptime("09121991", '%d%m%Y')
```

Note that you cannot use `input` to enter `09121991` because in Python 2:

- `input` evaluates the expression
- `09121991` is seen as an octal number, but invalid because it contains `9`

So the alternative is using `raw_input()`. That'll work.

BTW: If you need to pad with zeroes use `raw_input().zfill(8)`. No need to add the leading zeroes using that trick.